# lftp mirror file from server after deleting from local

Tags: sftp, mirror, lftp

I am using LFTP command to mirror some files from server to client. In my program system is somehow deleting few downloaded files on local machine.

When I run again the LFTP command it does not download locally deleted files from server. However I have seen that if I run LFTP command after a while, say 10 mins later, it downloads deleted files.

Is there any kind of locking period once files are mirrored?

Please see below command that I am using.

```
lftp sftp://user:pass@host:port -e 'mirror -r -i pattern -X pattern1 remote_directory local_directory; exit'
```

Please suggest